# undefined variable - ansible task role

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to add filter attribute as "**rejectattr**" to my task ( **installing kibana plugins**) but I'm getting some errors after running the playbook:

**my_vars.yaml**

```
    kibanaPlugins:
      - plugin: "wazuh_kibana"
        url: 'https://reposxxx'
      - plugin: "kibanaPrometheusExporter"
        url: "https://reposxxxx"
```

**My playbook:**

```
- name: List current kibana plugins
  command: "{{ kibanaPluginCommand }} list --allow-root"
  register: kibanaCurrentPlugins
  changed_when: false
  tags:
    - kibana-plugins


- name: Install kibana plugins 
  command: "{{ ansible_check_mode | ternary('echo', '') }} {{ kibanaPluginCommand }} install {{ item.url | default(item.plugin) }} --allow-root"
  with_items: "{{ kibanaPlugins | rejectattr('plugin', 'in', kibanaCurrentPlugins.stdout_lines)}}"
  changed_when: kibanaInstallingPluginsResult.stdout is search("Plugin")
  check_mode: false
  tags:
    - kibana-plugins
```

**errors:**

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was:
'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'plugin'

The error appears to be in '/builds/kibana/tasks/main.yml': line 166, column 3,
but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Install kibana plugins
  ^ here
```

**debug task:**

```
- name: debug for task install kibana plugin
  debug:
    msg: "{{ (kibanaPlugins | rejectattr('plugin', 'in' 
  kibanaCurrentPlugins.stdout_lines)) | list }}"
  tags:
    - kibana-plugins
```

**Output of debug task:**

```
TASK [kibana : Install kibana plugins xx.xx.xx] *************************** Monday 27 March 2023  15:29:01 +0000 (0:00:00.034)       0:00:42.121 **********  changed: [localhost] => {     "msg": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f9bcc9d1190>" }
```

Comment: What is the content of the `kibanaPlugins` variable? Please update your question to include that information.

Comment: Something seems off. Can you replace the `my_vars.yaml` section with the output of a `debug` task that shows the actual value of `kibanaPlugins` while the playbook is running? How are you reading in the `my_vars.yaml` file?

Comment: `TASK [kibana : Install kibana plugins xx.xx.xx] ***************************
Monday 27 March 2023  15:29:01 +0000 (0:00:00.034)       0:00:42.121 ********** 
changed: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f9bcc9d1190>"
}`

Comment: My goal is to create a task that is installing a list of kibana plugins mentioned in `kibanaPlugins` but first I'm checking/listing if there are any current kibana plugin installed and not interfere with my new  kibana plugin that I want to install them, that's why I chose `rejectattr('plugin', 'in', kibanaCurrentPlugins.stdout_lines)`

Comment: Your "install kibana plugins" tasks looks correct as written. What I'm trying to get you to do is show **in your question** (a) how you're setting the `kubanaPlugins` variable and (b) exactly what the content looks like in the output of a `debug` task. I see you've added the latter in a comment, but it is always better to update the question (because that makes the information more obvious and you have a lot more options for formatting it usefully).